# Why AsyncFileUpload enforces a Postback?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

I'm AjaxControlToolkit's AsyncFileUpload control to upload files to server. It is placed in an UpdatePanel but when someone uploads a new file, a post back occurs. Why a post back occurs while I've put AsyncFileUpload in UpdatePanel?

I've used sample form [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/pawanmishra/archive/2009/10/20/ajaxcontroltoolkits-asyncfileupload-control.aspx) and [here](http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/using_aspnet_ajax_control_toolkits_asyncfileupload_control.php).

Comment: Do you mean a full postback or a partial postback occurs?

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue, did you find a solution?